# NodeJS require error when running the server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I run into the following error when running `node server.js`:

[image]

Why does `require` throw an error? I am using Socket.IO, and my code in `server.js` is shown below:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');

server.listen(8890);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  console.log("new client connected");
  var redisClient = redis.createClient();
  redisClient.subscribe('message');

  redisClient.on("message", function(channel, message) {
    console.log("mew message in queue "+ message + "channel");
    socket.emit(channel, message);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    redisClient.quit();
  });

});
```

Comment: what versions of socket.io and express are you using?

Comment: when i install the packages i used `npm install express redis socket.io@"~0.8.1" --save` i used socket version 0.8.1 because the latest version is not installing properly..

Comment: See my answer, and if you continue getting install issues post those as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using Socket.io v0.8.1. You can resolve this by **at least installing v1.0.0**. I recommend the latest stable release, if you have no requirements/restraints on upgrading from prior versions.

The `require('io')(srv)` signature was released in v1.0.0. Plus v0.8.1 dates back to 2011; that is a long time and much has changed in Node, as well as Express and Socket.io.

Here is more about transitioning from version v0.9 and below to v1.0.0+: http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/

Here is where you can find version history of Socket.io: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/History.md

Comment: thank you sir.. I successfully installed the socket.io with a version of 1.0.0